# Interpolate 3 x (4 bits) values at once stored in a 2-byte variable

Tags: c, interpolation

I have 3 numbers stored in a 16-bit variable. These numbers have a maximum of
4 bits each and they are each stored in a 5-bit field in the following format in the 16-bit variable: `0x3DEF` (so there is one free (zero) bit after each value and the most significant bit is always zero).

I want to interpolate each separate number from the 16-bit variable with the respective numbers from another 16-bit variable like so: `(numberA * interpolation + numberB) >> 8)`, where the interpolation range is from 0 to 255.

Is there a faster way than extracting each value from the 16-bit variables, doing the interpolation, and then grouping them back together?

I want the results to be stored back in the 16-bit variable using the same format.

Comment: Why not use an array of 3 separate `unsigned char` (or `signed char`) values and use those in the expressions?  What's the benefit of the complicated storage?  (Don't claim that you're saving space; an array of 3 `char` occupies less space than an `int32_t`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need to feed these values to a system that needs it in that specific format in a int16_t variable. Also it's saving space, they are stored as int16_t, I just moved them to a 32bit variable hoping that would allow for some more room to create something faster

Comment: I'd be tempted to keep the values in an array of 3 `char` and assemble the 16-bit value from those on demand.  And read the value and split it on demand.  Use the array for the values that can be manipulated and convert from/to the external format when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that there won't be a faster way to do the manipulation than split, calculate (interpolate) and combine.  You can't simply multiply the 16-bit (or 32-bit) values, add and shift; you'd need more space around the values.  I came up with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct B3x4_Data
{
    char    data[3];
} B3x4_Data;

typedef uint16_t B3x4_Value;

static inline void b3x4_map_value_to_data(B3x4_Value value, B3x4_Data *data)
{
    data->data[0] = (value >>  0) & 0x0F;
    data->data[1] = (value >>  5) & 0x0F;
    data->data[2] = (value >> 10) & 0x0F;
}

static inline B3x4_Value b3x4_map_data_to_value(const B3x4_Data *data)
{
    return ((data->data[0] & 0x0F) <<  0) |
           ((data->data[1] & 0x0F) <<  5) |
           ((data->data[2] & 0x0F) << 10);
}

static inline B3x4_Value b3x4_interpolate(B3x4_Value valueA, uint8_t interpolate, B3x4_Value valueB)
{
    B3x4_Data dataA;
    B3x4_Data dataB;
    B3x4_Data result;
    b3x4_map_value_to_data(valueA, &dataA);
    b3x4_map_value_to_data(valueB, &dataB);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        result.data[i] = ((dataA.data[i] * interpolate + dataB.data[i]) >> 8) & 0x0F;

    return b3x4_map_data_to_value(&result);
}

static inline B3x4_Value B3x4_Init(uint8_t v1, uint8_t v2, uint8_t v3)
{
    return ((((v1) & 0x0F) << 10) |
            (((v2) & 0x0F) <<  5) |
            (((v3) & 0x0F) <<  0));
}

static void b3x4_print_value(B3x4_Value v)
{
    B3x4_Data d;
    b3x4_map_value_to_data(v, &d);
    printf("[0x%.4X = (0x%X,0x%X,0x%X)]", v, d.data[2], d.data[1], d.data[0]);
}

static void print_calculation(B3x4_Value v1, uint8_t i1, B3x4_Value v2, B3x4_Value r1)
{
    b3x4_print_value(v1);
    printf(" * %d + ", i1);
    b3x4_print_value(v2);
    printf(" = ");
    b3x4_print_value(r1);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    B3x4_Value v1 = B3x4_Init(0xF, 0xF, 0xF);
    B3x4_Value v2 = B3x4_Init(0xC, 0xB, 0xA);
    B3x4_Value v3 = B3x4_Init(0x7, 0x9, 0xC);
    B3x4_Value v4 = B3x4_Init(0xA, 0x6, 0x2);
    uint8_t i1 = 37;
    uint8_t i2 = 96;
    B3x4_Value r1 = b3x4_interpolate(v1, i1, v2);
    B3x4_Value r2 = b3x4_interpolate(v3, i2, v4);

    print_calculation(v1, i1, v2, r1);
    print_calculation(v3, i2, v4, r2);

    return 0;
}
```

Any self-respecting optimizer will ignore the 'shift by zero' operations, but showing them emphasizes the symmetry in the work.

That produces the output:

```
[0x3DEF = (0xF,0xF,0xF)] * 37 + [0x316A = (0xC,0xB,0xA)] = [0x0842 = (0x2,0x2,0x2)]
[0x1D2C = (0x7,0x9,0xC)] * 96 + [0x28C2 = (0xA,0x6,0x2)] = [0x0864 = (0x2,0x3,0x4)]
```